# How to handle routes in React which exist byt may not have data if user enters it straight into URL

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router-dom

There is React router route in Main.js as the error indicates line:95:
"/article/:article_id"

```
const Main = props => {
const { authUser, errors, removeError, currentUser } = props;
return(
<div className="">
<Switch>
<Route exact path="/article/:article_id" render={props => {
      return (
        <ArticleDetails 
         currentUser={currentUser}
         {...props}
        />
      )
 }} />
// lots of other routes
{/* Not found component */}
<Route component={PageNotFound} />
</Switch>
</div>
);
};
// and some redux state 

    function mapStateToProps(state) {
    return {
        currentUser: state.currentUser,
        errors: state.errors
    };
};

export default withRouter(connect(mapStateToProps, { authUser, removeError })(Main));
```

So, for example, there can be "/article/5" but there might not be "/article/6", article with an id of 6. 
I have a default component that loads when the route does not exist, but in this case, the route does exist, only dynamic data may not.

If article request returns no article when user types "/article/6/" in URL, he does get redirected back to "/articles" with "this.props.history.push('/articles');". 
ArticleDetails component fetches all data of an article, while parent component ArticlesList, has only few details with the link to ArticleDetails page, it does not pass article as prop.

```
class ArticleDetails extends Component {
  _isMounted = false;
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        article: null,
        lists: [],
        showBookmark: false,
        showPdf: false,
        showDelete: false
    };
    // binded methods...
  }

componentDidMount(){
    this._isMounted = true;
    if (this._isMounted) {
    let id = this.props.match.params.article_id;
    axios.get('/api/article/' + id)
      .then(res => {

          this.setState({
            article: res.data.article
          });

          return res.data.article;
      })
      .then(article => {
        if(!article)
        {
            this.props.history.push('/articles');
        }
        else if(this.props.currentUser.isAuthenticated)
        {
          return apiCall("post", `/api/article/${id}/checklike`)
            .then(res => { 
              let newState = Object.assign({}, this.state);
              newState.article.isLiked = res.isLiked;
              this.setState(newState);
            });
        }
      })
      .then( res => {
          let newState = Object.assign({}, this.state);
          if(this.props.currentUser.isAuthenticated)
          {
            newState.article.comments.map(comment => {
              let temp = comment.likes.find(like => like.user_id === 
              this.props.currentUser.user.id)
              if(temp) { comment.isLiked = true}
              else { comment.isLiked = false}
          })

          this.setState(newState);
          }
      })
      .catch(err => {
         return <Redirect to='/articles' />
      });

      this.getUserArticleLists();
    }

  };

// and also a small state
    const mapStateToProps = state => ({})

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(ArticleDetails);
```

but the user also gets this warning of a memory leak which sounds not cool and may signal that I'm doing something incorrectly. I added _isMounted property but I'm either doing it wrong or it does not help.

```
 componentWillUnmount() {
   this._isMounted = false;
 }
```

*"index.js:1 Warning: Can't perform a React state update on an unmounted component. This is a no-op, but it indicates a memory leak in your application. To fix, cancel all subscriptions and asynchronous tasks in the componentWillUnmount method.
    in ArticleDetails (created by ConnectFunction)
    in ConnectFunction (at Main.js:95)"*

Question is how to handle situations when component is loaded and only then it is known that the data does not exist or maybe the user is not allowed to access it and redirect the user properly? Am I missing some sort of middleware on the React that I should be using for such cases? or How should be URL access even handled in such cases?

P.S I'm new to React, I have a little redux store, but not getting very deep into it at the moment, trying to solve just by using react, as I'm currently doing the project which has almost no time left. But for future improvement, I accept all answers, feedback, I might not know basic practises so I appreciate every comment.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] to show code that causes the warning.

Comment: Edited. Don't know exactly what is causing it, but added my component cycle methods. I guess something is not good with asynchronous requests.